# Is bounded variation function monotonic in a small neighborhood?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I am reading Fourier analysis writen by Javier Duoandikoetxea. In the proof of theorem 1.2, he claimed that we may assume a BV function is monotonic in a neighborhood of a point since it is the difference of two monotonic functions. I know that BV function is difference of monotonic functions and also know that monotonic functions are differentiable almost everywhere but don't know why those imply there exist a neighborhood such that it is monotonic.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you define a BV function, but certainly the function $x\sin(1/x)$ is infinitely small near the origin, but fails to be monotonic there.

Comment: @Allawonder, OK. I knew. Although $x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not of bounded variation but $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is a counter-example. Thanks.